# The code does not work if there is a text box

Tags: javascript, html

Please help with this code

1. An example works well

---

```
date1 = new Date ,d0.innerHTML;
date2 = new Date("2017/09/26 06:30 PM");
```

2. When the date inside the text does not work

---

```
date1 = new Date ,d0.innerHTML;
date2 = new Date ,T1.value;
```

How do I make this code work?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the comma does.

Comment: `date1 = new Date(d0.innerHTML);
  date2 = new Date(T1.value);`

Comment: Welcome to SO Please take a little more time to understand how JavaScript syntax works. There are many beginner tutorials on the net

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you talk about a "text". I suppose that this is an HTML text input field. I think that you are refering to "T1", and I suppose that T1 is the name of the field.

Have you tried to refer to this field contents using document.forms[0].T1.value?

```
date1 = new Date (d0.innerHTML);
date2 = new Date (document.forms[0].T1.value);
```

Regards